# Work with NSManagedObject in different threads via MagicalRecords

Tags: ios, core-data, magicalrecord

I create entity Artist in main thread,
then pass it in background thread and associate with entity Album.

**How to do it correctly?**

```
- (IBAction)add:(id)sender
{
    Artist *artist = [Artist MR_createEntity];
    artist.title = @"Eminem";

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0),^{
        // here a large calculation
        Album *album = [Album MR_createEntity];
        album.title = @"Album 1";
        [artist setAlbums:[NSSet setWithArray:@[album]]];

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),^{
            [artist.managedObjectContext MR_saveToPersistentStoreAndWait];
        });
    });
}
```

Error:

```
MagicalRecordTest[2008:1803] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Illegal attempt to establish a relationship 'albums' between objects in different contexts (source = <Artist: 0x15eaa2d0>
```

Comment: You should really be using the specific thread calls from Magical Record for this. I think it's `performBlock`.

Answer (score 5):

You are violating one of the primary rules of Core Data.  A `NSManagedObjectContext` and its associated `NSManagedObject` instances can only be accessed on the thread that created them.  You can pass `NSManagedObjectID` instances around but not `NSManagedObject` instances.

Further, when you create a relationship between two `NSManagedObject` instances; both instances **must** be from the same `NSManagedObjectContext` otherwise you will get the error you are seeing above.

Instead of the approach you have above, re-fetch the `Artist` in the block. I could provide sample code on how to do this with Core Data but you will need to research how to do that with MagicalRecord.

Comment: +1 to refetch in MagicalRecord you can do `[artist inThreadContext]` I believe. Something like that anyway.

Comment: The MR_inThreadContext method has been deprecated because it can occasionally cross thread boundaries when used with GCD queues. Just create a new context instead, they're lightweight and meant for exactly this reason.

Answer (score 3):

Marcus is correct in that you need to be aware of the contexts you're using and need to use them in only a single queue or thread. MagicalRecord has a nice API for managing this. In your case, you should do something more like:

```
- (void) add;
{
    NSManagedObjectContext *mainContext = [NSManagedObjectContext MR_defaultContext];
    Artist *artist = [Artist MR_createInContext:mainContext];
    [mainContext MR_saveToPersistentStoreAndWait];

    [MagicalRecord saveWithBlock:^(NSManagedObjectContext *localContext) {
        Artist *localArtist = [artist MR_inContext:localContext];
        localArtist.title = @"Album...";
    }];
}
```

MagicalRecord will set up the save queue and perform things in the right place, as long as you remember that first, you cannot transfer temporary objects between NSManagedOjbectContexts. And second, you must use a separate context for each thread/queue/block. The localContext in this case is created for you, and once the block is complete, MagicalRecord will attempt to save that local/temp context for you.